# UIImagePickerController capture Video and Image with same instance

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Is this possible to capture Image and Video with the same instance of UIImagePickerController?
If yes than how?
I am creating a sample in which If I use

```
[imagePicker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"]];
[imagePicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];
```

with my ImagePicker Instance the `takePicture` method don't call its delegate method. And if I remove these two lines my `startVideoCapture` returns NO.

Please let me know if this is possible or not. If yes then please let me know any tutorial or something.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : removed incorrect answer, please see answer from user2374993.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just set UIImagePickerController media types for both image and video. 
For example:

```
mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

That will open the Camera with both options.
Make sure you check the media type the user chose in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can. On top of what `user2374993` said, you can also capture a video and (for example) use the first frame of that video as the photo.

It depends if you want the user to be able to switch between photo and video (like the previous answer), or if you want to take a photo and a video with the same button at the same time. If that's the case then my solution can work.

Simply catch the frame that you need (usually the first or the last really) and use that as your photo.